# Jackson serialization: JsonInclude.Include.NON_ABSENT doesn't ignore null value

Tags: java, json, spring, serialization, jackson

What should I use to ignore fields with null values?
I used `JsonInclude.Include.NON_ABSENT` but it didn't help.
I have classes

```
@Builder
@Value
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_ABSENT)
public class ProductsMessageBody implements Message {
    @NonNull
    Integer clientId;

    @NonNull
    Long subsId;

    @Singular
    List<ProductPart> products;
}
```

ProductPart class

```
@Builder
@Value
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_ABSENT)
public class ProductPart {
    @NonNull
    Long productId;

    @NonNull
    Integer offerId;

    @Builder.Default
    @NonNull
    ActivationPeriodPart activationPeriod = ActivationPeriodPart.builder().build();

    @Singular
    List<ValuePart> values;

    @Builder.Default
    @NonNull Date orderDateTime = new Date(1529897304000L);

    PayingInformationPart payingInformation;
}
```

PayingInformationPart class

```
@Builder
@Value
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_ABSENT)
public class PayingInformationPart {
    Boolean isPaying;
    Date payingDateTime;
}
```

In output I still have `payingInformation = null`:

```
{
    "clientId": 1,
    "subsId": 5,
    "products": [{
        "productId": 8,
        "offerId": 11111,
        "activationPeriod": {
            "dateFrom": "2018-06-24T22:08:24+03:00",
            "dateTo": "2999-06-24T22:08:24+03:00"
        },
        "values": [{
            "value": 55,
            "characteristic": {
                "code": "xx"
            }
        }],
        "orderDateTime": "2018-06-25T06:28:24+03:00",
        "payingInformation": null
    }]
}
```

I build object this way

```
    public static final ProductsMessageBody MESSAGE = ProductsMessageBody.builder()
            .clientId(1)
            .subsId(5L)
            .product(ProductPart.builder()
                    .productId(8L)
                    .offerId(11111)
                    .value(ValuePart.builder()
                            .characteristic(CharacteristicName.builder().code(
                                    'xxx'
                            ).build())
                            .value(55)
                            .build())

                    .build())

            .build();
```

I used JsonInclude.Include.NON_ABSENT and expected that there is no "payingInformation" in output. Could you explain how I can fix it, please? I don't need payingInformation = null in output.
I tried to use `JsonInclude.Include.NON_ABSENT` with fields but it didn't help either

Answer (score 0):

Remove the @Value annotation from all three classes (ProductsMessageBody, ProductPart, and PayingInformationPart).

Add the @Setter annotation from Lombok to each class to generate the setters for the fields. This will allow Jackson to set values in the objects.

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor // Add this for default constructor
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_ABSENT)
```

Comment: I added @Setter, @Data, @NoArgsConstructor to all classes (ProductsMessageBody, ProductPart, and PayingInformationPart) 
and I got an error ``` java: constructor ProductPayingInformationPart in class ProductPayingInformationPart 
cannot be applied to given types; required: no arguments found: java.lang.Boolean,java.util.Date reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length```